# Projecting Raster Z-Values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcmap

I have a DEM raster that I'm trying to convert from an NAD State Plane to a WGS84 in ArcMap. This is going from feet to meters. I can get it to work, but it multiplies the z-value by the feet to meters conversion, which is totally wrong. So its treating my Z as meters and trying to convert it to feet. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please update your question to indicate exactly which NAD StatePlane projection you are using as your source. It may be easiest to screenshot the ArcMap Projection info tab for the source layer.  Also, please tell us which ArcMap version you are using.